# Nested ILookup - Argument ype error

Tags: c#, .net, grouping, lookup

Consider the following object:

```
class Menu{
    public int Section {get; set;}
    public string Parent {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Url {get; set;}
    /* more */
}
```

I am getting a list of these objects and I want to group them by section and then inside each section I want to group them by parent so I used the following structure:

```
ILookup<int, ILookup<string, Menu>> MenuStructure = 
         menuList.ToLookup(m => m.Section, menuList.ToLookup(m => m.Parent));
```

but I'm getting this error:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.ILookup<int,MyNamespace.Menu>' to
>   'System.Linq.ILookup<int,System.Linq.ILookup<string,MyNamespace.Menu>>'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code you've got that's producing that error? `ToLookup` takes a `Func` or an `IEqualityComparer` as its second argument, neither of which you're providing.

Comment: Using your code I got `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.ILookup<string,CrashTest.Menu>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>'`

Comment: @Thomas angle brackets **need** to be within code formatting (either four-space-indent or backticks) otherwise they do not appear correctly. Look at the side-by-side comparison of [the edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31070930/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a grouping `.GroupBy()` first:

```
ILookup<int, ILookup<string, Menu>> MenuStructure = 
        menuList.GroupBy(m => m.Section).ToLookup(g => g.Key, v => v.ToLookup(m => m.Parent));
```

otherwise the inner .ToLookup acts on the whole list, not the list provided by the first .ToLookup

Full code for a .net fiddle:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    class Menu {
      public int Section {get; set;}
      public string Parent {get; set;}
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string Url {get; set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    { 
        var menuList = new List<Menu>();

        ILookup<int, ILookup<string, Menu>> MenuStructure = 
             menuList.GroupBy(m => m.Section).ToLookup(g => g.Key, v => v.ToLookup(m => m.Parent));
    }
}
```